# IE10 ajax calling Success on Server Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I am calling this method with IIS turned off :-

```
$.ajax({
            data: dataToSend,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error");

            },

            success: function (data) {
                alert("Success");

            },
            url: strUrl
        });
```

Even with IIS turned off, it always calls success and never goes to error.This bug is happening in IE 10 but not in IE 8.

I looked into jquery site and it is been reported but looks like it cannot be fixed.
Can anybody please help with workaround ??

Comment: maybe this help you: http://maxheapsize.com/2010/04/26/how-to-detect-if-your-server-is-down-when-making-jquery-ajax-calls/

Comment: You may want to turn ajax caching off (IE is notorious for serving you a cached response rather than going back to the server).  Try adding `cache: false` as a `$.ajax()` option.